LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method
I am calculating birthdays of the employees. Issue is that DateOfBirth column datatype is varchar (string) in database and i cannot change it. Someone else created it in the system. DateOfBirth is saved in UK format i.e dd/MM/yyyy.
Here is the code:
public void GetBirthdays()
{
    int dateOffset = 3;

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(dateOffset);

   using (var ctx = new ctxEntities())
    {
         var staff = (from s in ctx.Employees
              let date = DateTime.ParseExact(s.DateOfBirth, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
              where date >= today
              && date <= maxDate
             );

        var list = staff.ToList(); //Exception on this line, which is mentioned below.
    }
  }

This is the exception:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

How I can resolve it?
Thanks

Do you have any control over the database at all? Could you add a computed column that is something like DateOfBirthAsDateTime AS TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DateOfBirth, 103), then add that to your model as a DateTime property, and just use normal date comparisons?

You've not stated which entity framework version you are using, but you may also be able to use FromSql, e.g. ctx.Employees.FromSql($"SELECT e.* FROM dbo.Employees AS e WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, e.DateOfBirth, 103) >= {today} AND TRY_CONVERT(DATE, e.DateOfBirth, 103) <= {maxDate}");.      As an aside, are you expecting to have a lot of unborn employees in your database?

The string formatted date may be a pain since I would assume the entity is mapping it as a string rather than a DateTime. One option specific to your specific use case if the # of dates for upcoming birthdays is reasonable (I.e. one month or less) would be to create a range of date strings to search. For example:
var days = Enumerable.Range(0, offset)
    .Select(offset => today.AddDays(offset).ToString("dd/MM"))
    .ToArray(); 

However, this won't include Feb 29 on non-leap years for those special people that were born on Feb 29th, so to be thorough:
if (today <= new DateTime(today.Year, 2, 28) 
    && today.AddDays(offset) >= new DateTime(today.Year, 3, 1)
    && !days.Contains("02/29"))
    days.Add("02/29");

This should give you an array of the Day/Month from the Dates for the offset, so if offset is 3 days, today, tomorrow, and the day after. "21/10", "22/10", "23/10". While it would be nice to feed this into a Linq query such as:
// Will not work. :(
var staff = ctx.Employees
    .Where(e => days.Any(d => e.DateOfBirth.StartsWith(d)))
    .ToList();

EF Core cannot translate this down to SQL. One option would be to use a PredicateBuilder via something like LinqKit which would look something like:
var predicate = days.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.False<Employee>(), 
    (p,d) => p = p.Or(e => e.DateOfBirth.StartsWith(d)));
var staff = ctx.Employees
    .Where(predicate)
    .ToList();

This will essentially build an expression like WHERE (employee.DateOfBirth LIKE '10/10%' OR employee.DateOfBirth LIKE '11/10%' ...) which will be limited to 2000 or so dates based on how many parameters can be sent to a query. It will work, but honestly not very easily readable when reviewing the code in the future.  However it's worth noting that even with this, the resulting query cannot leverage indexes to find these employees, so it's not going to be particularly fast over a large set of employees.
A simpler compromise would be to fetch the date of births and employee IDs into memory then perform the check in memory. You then have a set of employee IDs to load:
var birthdayEmployeeIds = ctx.Employees
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(e => new {e.EmployeeId, e.DateOfBirth})
    .AsEnumerable() // materialize the set.
    .Where(e => days.Any(d => e.DateOfBirth.StartsWith(d)))
    .Select(e => e.EmployeeId)
    .ToList();

var staff = ctx.Employees
    .Where(e => birthdayEmployeeIds.Contains(e.EmployeeId))
    .ToList();

This is a compromise to materializing a query that cannot be converted to SQL. Rather than fetching all employee data into memory, which could get rather large, we fetch just the employee ID and date of birth string and materialize that. From that we can use the simpler, easier to read Linq expression for matching the start of the DoB string with our target range, and get the resulting matched employee IDs. With that list of IDs we can fetch (and/or project) the applicable staff.
